# Limit to infinity of trigonometry

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

\begin{align*}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n\left(\left(1-\cos^2\frac{16}{n}\right)\sin\frac{16}{n}\right)^{1/3}}{4}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n\left(\sin^2\frac{16}{n}\sin\frac{16}{n}\right)^{1/3}}{4}= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n\sin\frac{16}{n}}{4}
\end{align*}
I'm looking for my mistake, where my answer to the question is $0$, but according to the answer choices, it must be $2$,$3$,$4$, or $5$.

Thanks

Comment: How do you find $0$?

Comment: The answer is 4. It's a standrad problem. Replace $\frac{1}{n}$ by $x$ and change the limit as well.

Comment: THe answer to *what* question is 0?  I don't see any question whatsoever asked in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may recall that, as $x \to 0$,
$$
\frac{\sin x}x\longrightarrow1
$$ thus, as $n \to \infty$, one gets
$$
\frac{n\sin \frac{16}n}4=4\:\frac{\sin \frac{16}n}{\frac{16}n} \longrightarrow 4\cdot1=4.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $4$. What is the limit of $\sin(ax)/x$ as $x \to 0$? Then replace $a = 16$ and $x = 1/n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\sin\frac{16}{n}}{4}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}4\frac{\sin\frac{16}{n}}{\frac{16}{n}}$$
$$=4\lim_{\frac{16}{n}\to 0}\frac{\sin\frac{16}{n}}{\frac{16}{n}}$$
$$=4\times 1$$
$$=4$$

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you can also use l'Hospitals Rule.

$$\frac{1}{4}\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sin(\frac{16}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Applying the limit gives an ideterminate 0/0 so we apply l'Hospitals Rule

$$\frac{1}{4}\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\cos(\frac{16}{n})}{\frac{-1}{n^2}} \cdot \frac{-16}{n^2} $$

$$4\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos(\frac{16}{n})$$

Applying the limit gives 4